# Is there a "must-use" attribute in PHP or PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is it possible to specify, either in plain PHP 8+ or PHPDoc that a function return value must be used, like the [Rust equivalent](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-must_use-attribute)?

Imagine a function:

```php
public function doSomething(): ImportantObject {
  return (new ImportantObject)->withImportantStuff();
}
```

I would like to annotate it something like this:

```php
/**
 * @mustUse
 * @return ImportantObject
 */
public function doSomething(): ImportantObject {
  return (new ImportantObject)->withImportantStuff();
}
```

Or:

```php
#[must_use]
public function doSomething(): ImportantObject {
  return (new ImportantObject)->withImportantStuff();
}
```

The use case for this would be so developers get a warning in their IDE that they have to use the value or, otherwise, their code would not be sound or be less robust.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the defintion of "use". In PHP an expression is a statement and vice versa, so `"fred";` is a valid complete statement. It just doesn't do anything.

If something returns a value then that value is used. In your example `doSomething();` as a statement does use the return value, it just doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Same applies to Rust. Example program `fn main() { "test"; }` runs without issues, yet the Rust compiler knows that you haven't used the return value at call-site (if the function or type is annotated with `#[must_use]`). Expressions turn into statements by using a semicolon which applies to PHP as well. The idea would be that the IDE could use this information to highlight that a return value has not been used at **call site**.

Comment: I now see you've tagged phpdoc. You're looking for something IDE specific rather than part of the language. Sorry I missed that on first reading.

Comment: It does not have to be IDE specific, but should be something that works out of the box – or using a library. Specifically, the question can be interpreted as "Can I do this using PHP only, so my IDE will detect it just like everything else?" and not "How do I get my IDE to do this?"